# What is wrong with this quicksort?

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am reviewing topics for a programming interview,

and started doing some algorithms. I've written this quicksort, out of a pseudo code from a book.

Its exactly the same, but it does not work.
It does compile and runs without a problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public static void quicksort(int [] array , int i, int j){

       if (i<j) {
            int p= partition(array, i, j);
            quicksort(array,i,p-1);
            quicksort(array,p+1,j);
      }

    }
    public static int partition(int [] array, int i, int j){

    int val= array[i];
    int h= i;
    for (int k = i+1; k<j; k++) {
        if (array[k]<val) {
            h++;
            swap(array,h,k);
        }
        swap(array,i,h);
    }
   return h;

}
  public static void swap (int a[],int indexa, int indexb){

    int aux= a[indexa];
    a[indexa]=a[indexb];
    a[indexb]=aux;

}
```

In main:

```
    int [] a= new int[]{1,3,17,5,6,7,11,19,4,2,15,8,13,15,9,14,12,16,18,10};
    quicksort(a,0,a.length-1);
```

Actual text from book

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzxb8ezvryrq6ox/2014-02-27%2022.04.56.jpg

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kmavnvzbrvp7xg/2014-02-27%2022.05.05.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work. It does compile and runs without a problem".  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your main method?

Comment: If it's not working, it isn't "exactly the same"... or the book is wrong, which is possible. I'd suggest rereading, operation by operation, to make absolutely sure that you've adapted it correctly. Or go looking for other implementations of Quicksort on the web -- there should be plenty of them -- and compare them to yours. Or look at all the Quicksort questions ans answers under *Related* at right and see if they help you.

Comment: @Drogba has a good point. How are you invoking this? What's the input, and what result are you getting?

Comment: @DavidWallace . It doesnt work, as the result in the end, is not correct (array inst ordered)

Comment: example:
int [] a= new int[]{1,3,17,5,6,7,11,19,4,2,15,8,13,15,9,14,12,16,18,10};
quicksort(a,0,a.length-1);

Comment: What does that example return?

Comment: @DavidWallace 

QUICKSORT:
BEFORE
[1][3][17][5][6][7][11][19][4][2][15][8][13][15][9][14][12][16][18][10]
AFTER
[1][3][2][4][5][6][7][13][14][11][8][15][17][18][15][9][19][12][16][10]

Comment: Did you intend to have two calls to `swap` inside `partition`?  That doesn't seem right to me - you're swapping things round even if they're already in the correct order.

Comment: From what is done in the book, the swapping is only to order in two directions, higher, or lower. Is not important if members of the higher group are ordered. It will be ordered recursively by having the head always ordered.

Comment: I've added photos of the book with the pseudo code! =)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You clearly have 2 mistakes in your implementation.  Compare what you did line by line and you will see them.  Or try to read and understand your code.  Or step through it.

Comment: @MK. Ive read it twice now =/, Can't find anything. Are you possitive?

Comment: From what your book describes, the 2nd swap call in partition method should be outside the for loop.

Comment: @Drogba you are right! Those are the 2 mistakes MK was talking about heh.

Comment: @MK. Found them! lol. the indentation in that book is terrible!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your codes and add some message between the calls.

First change:

```
for (int k = startIndex + 1; k < endIndex; k++)
```

to

```
for (int k = startIndex + 1; k <= endIndex; k++)
```

Second change:
Move the `swap` call outside the for loop in `partition`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = { 1, 3, 17, 5, 6, 7, 11, 19, 4, 2, 15, 8, 13, 15, 9, 14, 12, 16, 18, 10 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static void quicksort(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        System.out.println("quicksort(" + Arrays.toString(array) + ", " + startIndex + ", "
                + endIndex + ")");
        if (startIndex < endIndex) {
            int p = partition(array, startIndex, endIndex);
            quicksort(array, startIndex, p - 1);
            quicksort(array, p + 1, endIndex);
        }
    }

    public static int partition(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        System.out.println("partition(" + Arrays.toString(array) + ", " + startIndex + ", "
                + endIndex + ")");
        int startValue = array[startIndex];
        int h = startIndex;
        for (int k = startIndex + 1; k <= endIndex; k++) {
            if (array[k] < startValue) {
                h++;
                swap(array, h, k);
            }
        }
        swap(array, startIndex, h);
        return h;
    }

    public static void swap(int a[], int indexa, int indexb) {
        System.out.println("Before Swap: " + Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(a[indexa] + " <-> " + a[indexb]);
        int aux = a[indexa];
        a[indexa] = a[indexb];
        a[indexb] = aux;
        System.out.println("After Swap: " + Arrays.toString(a));
    }
```

Output is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

Comment: Correct! the 2 mistakes were, the condition was not k<=j, and the second swap had to be out of the for loop.
Thanks to MK and everyone too!